# Unarchiving and initializing SKScene From .sks

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

In WWDC 2014 Session 608, Apple demonstrates how you can set up a scene via an .sks file. Prior to this I would create an SKScene (in my OS X SpriteKit app) via the following code in the `AppDelegate.m` class:

```
SKScene *scene = [SomeSKSceneClass sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)]; //this calls the initWithSize method in my SKScene class
```

It would be in the `initWithSize` method that I would set up the class. However, now that the scene is being set via the `unarchiveFromFile` method in `AppDelegate.m`, where should I call my Scene's init method? Should it be done in the `didMoveToView` method?

Here's what it looks like now. This code is from the AppDelegate.m class:

```
GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
```

I hope this is clear, if not I can add more details. I really need some clarification. Please set me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you unarchive a scene from a file it's `initCoder:` is called by default. So you can either setup your scene in that, or use the didMoveToView method

Comment: Okay. So essentially there's no real need for an init method in that case. Or is it that `initCoder:` is that init method?

Comment: `initCoder:` is the init method, Classes which conform to the NSCoding protocol implements it and use [NSCoder's decoding methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003632) to assign values to their properties. Conversely, When you encode an object which conforms to NSCoding it's encodeWidthCoder: is called to encode all of it's properties. Note: subclasses should always call super encode/decode so that all the object's data is saved/loaded

Comment: Please upgrade your comment to an answer. Been scouring the web for this.